# How to override bootstrap styles with custom ones in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to override the default theme for the navbar in my rails page but it only seems to work with `!important` most of the time.

Is their any way I could have my custom stylesheet loaded last in the precompiler?

It seems to only be a problem when changing the navbar styles.  I have my navbar in a separate header partial.  Could that be it?

**custom.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';

$light-blue: #01579b;
$light-grey: #f5f5f5;

/* main-nav-bar */
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
}
.nav.navbar-nav a, .navbar-brand {
  color: $light-blue !important;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar-nav .active a {
  background-color: $light-grey !important;
}
.navbar-nav a:hover {
  background-color: $light-grey !important;
}
```

**application.scss**

```
/*
 *= require_tree
 *= require_self
*/
```

**html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OBOOK</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <%= link_to 'Home', root_path %>
                    </li>
                    <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Users', users_path %></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <%= link_to 'Profile', current_user, class: "dropdown-toggle", data: {toggle: "dropdown"} %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Settings', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as: <%= link_to current_user.email, current_user %></p>
                <% else %>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %></li>
                </ul>
                <% end %>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you include [bootstrap as a gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) (If you aren't already). Then you could drill down into the gem files and customise the existing CSS in there for instance.

You'll find the styles here:

```
app/vendor/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/.
```

Keep in mind that if you update your gems, these custom changes will in all likelihood be overwritten.

**Alternative Approach**

If you go to [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), and click on the “Customise” link, you’ll be taken to the page where you can customise Bootstrap to do exactly what you need it to do, this includes messing with the default color scheme to a certain extent.

Comment: Never change gem source code. It is absolutely bad practice.

Comment: i've included the 'bootstrap-sass' gem in my app but i do not see a app/vendor/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/ in my app folder.  under the vendor dir I see an assets dir.

Comment: @gmrash I totally agree, that's why I proposed an alternative approach. But to purely answer the question as asked, it's doable.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place? yourappname/vendor/bundle/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.5/assets/stylesheets/*

Comment: This is a horrible idea. You should not be editing the gem's source.

Comment: @DaniG2k I totally agree, that's why I proposed an alternative approach. But to purely answer the question as asked, it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

require your custom css file or folder below in application.css
If it will not help, see full chain of classes in Chrome webdeb and past on to you custom file.

Comment: should i require it under require_self in my application.scss?

Comment: sorry i'm not sure I fully understand your answer.  What is chrome webdeb?